# Simple (but large) read/write of time series data in python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, bigdata

I'm having trouble working out how to approach my particular problem (perhaps because there are too many options!) with respect to storing simple time series data using python.

All I want to do is store and access a really long one dimensional list of 16 bit integers. I don't even necessarily need to store an index, as it can be implicitly derived from the order of the samples. But I need a fast append operation.

The problem is that I expect to have *about* 100GB of data which needs to be recorded to disk on the fly at 100M samples/sec (I've tested and my SSD setup can handle 400-500MB/sec writes), and with only ~14GB of RAM. My initial idea was to basically write it to individual CSV files in chunks of 100M rows, but it seems like this would waste a lot of space (a 16 bit integer can take up to 5 bytes as a string instead of 2). Other ideas included using msgpack/npz/raw binary files for chunks, and while I'm more than happy to implement this myself, I'm trying to work out if there is a solution which already exists.

As I don't know exactly the number of samples I need beforehand, I think this means that numpy's memmap is not suitable.

Later, I also need to slice the data between two indices for processing without loading the entire dataset into memory. This doesn't happen while the recording is occurring, only after.

I think the pandas HDFStore is what I am after, but I am unsure of some of the best practices.

Specifically,

1. Given a very simple data format, what are the implications of lots of nodes (one node per chunk) vs a single node using HDFStore in pandas? If the former is better, what would be good chunk size?
2. Are HDFStores the best way to do disk-backed high performance sequential reads and writes in pandas? Random access is not important.
3. Is my problem in the domain of pandas? In this situation, pandas seems like overkill to me.

Any other tips or recommendations would be appreciated. Really, what I need is the list object in python, but which also has support for being quickly chunked to and from the disk.

Comment: Is the 100GB of data generated on the fly or already saved?

Comment: Why not use the HDF5 library directly and split the file later? Doesn't look like Pandas gives you any benefit.

Comment: @sihrc: It's generated on the fly from some hardware instrumentation.

Comment: @gandu: I was looking at pytables, which is a python wrapper around HDF5 (also used by pandas). But perhaps that is even overkill also?

Comment: @jeremy What did you end up choosing?

Comment: h5py. I wrote an in-memory double buffer system where data was written sequentially into a numpy array and then when the array was big enough it was flushed to disk and the buffers swapped. Worked great.

Comment: But I also needed a good SSD for it to keep up ;)

Answer (score 4):

The London group for my firm created arctic.  It uses numpy byte arrays, compressed with lz4, and split into chunks to send into mongodb.  In Boston, we're building out other features around this, but we find it works great.

It has great performance for slurping the whole thing out at once.

https://github.com/manahl/arctic

Have a look and see if it can work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use a single raw binary file. If you write the data in chunks this should have very little overhead. After data acquisition is done you can memmap the file and slice away. Example with numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

CHUNKSIZE = 2**24  # Requires tuning

def get_chunks_from_somewhere(n):
    """Generate dummy data."""
    for _ in range(n):
        yield np.random.randint(2**16, size=CHUNKSIZE).astype(np.uint16)

with open('temp.dat', 'wb') as fih:
    for chunk in get_chunks_from_somewhere(100):
        chunk.tofile(fih)
```

Regardless of file format, the real issue I think is that you have to write to disk asynchronously, otherwise it may block reading from the instrument (?).